# How to check whether an input string consist of integers

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I'm trying to make a while loop where the condition checks that the first four elements of a string are not integers. Here's my code, somehow it doesn't work. I tried using the isdigit function from the ctype.h header.

```
char tr_code[200];
char *endptr;

scanf("%s", &tr_code);
fd_code=strtol(tr_code,&endptr,10);

while(strlen(tr_code)!=4 && isdigit(tr_code[0])==0 && isdigit(tr_code[1])==0 && isdigit(tr_code[2])==0 && isdigit(tr_code[3])==0)
{
    printf("\nInvalid Code. please enter another '4-digit' Code: ");
    scanf("%s", &tr_code);
    fd_code=strtol(tr_code,&endptr,10);
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? what are the symptoms?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What did you expect, and what actually happened?

Comment: i expected the loop to keep going if the input are not integer. i didnt just make the input type integer because i will need the string variable later on

Answer (score 2):

You're using `&&`, but `||` is what you should be using:

```
while(strlen(tr_code) != 4 || !isdigit(tr_code[0]) || !isdigit(tr_code[1]) || !isdigit(tr_code[2]) || !isdigit(tr_code[3]))
```

With `&&`, any input that's four characters long, or has a digit in any of the first four positions (even if that memory is leftovers from the last input, since the string could be shorter) will pass.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC 'scanf' signature returns an integer, which is number of characters read at the terminal.